# How would you convert any document to a preview image?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-office, document, preview

I am using .NET and am looking for a way to convert just about any document into a preview image. I say any, but the priorities are Office Documents, PDF, and most image files.

I would assume that I can somehow build upon the Windows Explorer's ability to preview documents... but I do not know how.

What would you do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows Vista you can use the [preview handler API](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/PreviewApp.aspx) to either write a preview handler or use a preview handler to display a preview in your application. The link contains code that shows you how. [Here's an example Photoshop preview handler](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/PhotoshopPreviewHandler.aspx) that also goes over some background information that might be useful.

Finally, [here is an example that uses C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpf_vista_preview_handler.aspx). It's a WPF application that uses the C# class `COMStream` to get the preview data from a preview handler (which is an unmanaged COM object).